# Adding to a List Box from List without iteration

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

I am looking into having a single string command to put a all items of a list into a Listbox without using a loop. Is it possible?

I have been using:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = evenNumbers;
```

But that didn't do anything and I'm not sure why.

Also tried:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(evenNumbers);
```

But didn't work either. Note my (loop) code is functional, I am just trying to improve formatting.

Comment: It's just List full of strings. But I had a further look and it seems my problem is more than just that. When Converting String[] to a List<String> I get a really weird output. I was testing it by putting it to string and I got: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of my expected "1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: I will shortly, just checking first if I can't solve it myself

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the `DataSource` first.

```
ListBox1.DataSource = null;
ListBox1.DataSource = evenNumbers;
```